# Develop a Maven 3 plugin that provides some boilerplate files for compilation process

Tags: java, maven, groovy, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am writing a simple plugin that would make some files *visible* for other plugins during compilation.

Imagine I have this project structure (this structure is present in quite a few projects I maintain):

```
/
| -- /src
|    |---- /main
|          |------ /assembly
|                  |---------- file1
|                  |---------- file2
|                  |---------- fileN
|          |------ /java
|          |------ /resources
|
| -- pom.xml
```

I want to avoid having to keep everything under `/assembly` in each of my projects. I want to store the *default files* in a separate artifact/file e.g.

```
/
| -- /src
|    |---- /main
|          |------ /assembly
|                  |---------- file1
|                  |---------- file2
|                  |---------- fileN
```

I want my plugin to *merge* my project with the *default files* during compilation.

I also need to be able to selectively override the *default files*, so say I have 200 default files in `/assembly` but in one project I need to provide different `file2`, or add a `fileN+1`.

I think I could try a `shade` or other *merging* plugin but the *merged project* is NOT the end result in my case (plus I want to learn writing plugins).

The point is that I'd plug my plugin into `generate-resoruces` (or sth), and there is a plugin in the project (bound to `package`) that **expects** to find it's configuration in `/assembly`.

And this is what I want to achieve: **provide a default set of files** (in arbitrary directories), **be able to override them** and **make the merged result visible to next plugins**.

---

I came to this code:

```
Artifact artifact = project.dependencyArtifacts.find { 
   /* find the dependency with boilerplate files */  
}

JarFile jar = new JarFile(artifact.file)
jar.entries().each {
  /* make the entries visible to other next plugins */
}
```

And this is where I'm stuck. What should I do with the dependency's files in order to make them visible to next plugins?

Comment: I think you should provide a detailed use case instead of speaking in abstract terms.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen ok, I've rewritten the question. I hope it's more clear now!

Answer (score 0):

"I want my plugin to merge my project with the default files during compilation."
Well, this is the way to go:
It doesn't matter where your file resides.
Just copy them to the expected folder , leaving existing files untouched.
Make your default artifact use a different folder for storing the default files,
so that while unpacking there are somehwere located in your current project.
Specify this artifact as dependecy.
Copy them from there .. fine?
If this doesn't fit:
Provide your own implementation for unpacking artifacts.
I did so when building a maven plugin for C / C++ - artifacts, based on the work of Mark 
Donszelmann's nar-naven-plugin.
It isn't too hard.

```
List dependencies = this.getMavenProject().getDependencies();
    Iterator<Dependency> it = dependencies.iterator();
    String baseDir = this.getLocalRepository().getBasedir();
```

with 
   getMavenProject() returning MavenProject and getLocalRepository ArtifactRepository.

From there you can construct the path to your zip (jar), then unpack it with java.util.zip -
 classes and copy the default files.

Comment: I'm sorry I am not sure if this is related

Comment: It is just another way, if everything else fails. This way you can do pretty much anything while compiling with maven, as it is meant to hook in the maven lifecycle. You can depackage your default -artifact for yourself and copy the files in it to any location you want overwriting files or leave them untouched if they exist. It's just freedom of choice.